# Can't see my session variable in the third/last page?

Tags: php, macos

I'm having trouble viewing the session variable in the last page.  User should be able to submit a name, then the second page should ask you to "click here" to view the name or session variable in the final page.
Thank you for the help!

1) first page submits name with form:

```
<form action="Cookies&SessionVariables2.php" method="post">
    <img src="question.png" alt="WhatIsYourAlias?">
    <input name="alias" size="60" type="text">
    <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

2) second page says "Click here to view it":

```
<?php
//Handle the form if it has been submitted:
if (isset($_POST['alias'])){

    //Send the cookies:
    setcookie('alias',$_POST['alias']);
}
?>

<?php

//Check if the form has been submitted:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //Handle the form:
    if((!empty($_POST['alias']))){

        //Do session stuff
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['alias'] = 
        $_POST['alias'];

        //Message to be printed:
        echo $msg = '<p>Your Alias has been entered! Click <a href="Cookies&SessionVariables3.php">here</a> to view it!</p>';
     }

        //Forgot field
        else {
            print'<p>Awww! You did not submit your Alias! Please click <a href="Cookies&SessionVariables.php">here</a> and try again!</p>';
        } 
}     
?>
```

3) third page should show the session variable:

```
<?php

//Need the session:
session_start();

print '<p>Hello, ' . $_SESSION['alias'] . '!</p>';
?>
```

Comment: Put your `session_start();` at the very top of each page just inside the `<?php` tag - not inside the conditional.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for responding. It works now in MAMP, but when I upload it to the remote site it says things like this: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: That usually means there is whitespace between your PHP tag and the`session_start()` e.g. if you have put a return and indented it. There must be absolutely nothing output to the browser before it. Hope that works.

Comment: I noticed a lot of sites saying the whitespace. I removed whitespace and indenting. I also tried putting the session_start(); at the top of the page.  It moved the 'Warning' error at the top of my page, but didn't eliminate it. hmmmm wonder what it is

Comment: Steve....IT WORKS!!!!! I was thinking at the top meant above html.....well you meant the very top above the <!DOCTYPE>. I don't know what I was thinking.....It works perfectly now! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sessions are my favourite way of getting stuff done that can't quite be done with hidden inputs and JavaScript to carry values across pages. May be a silly thought but you might be able to reduce the number of pages you have by submitting the page to itself where possible rather than always having to go to a new page. That depends on your site design of course. I usually put all my PHP there at the top and drop little slugs into the HTML for values. Well done!